# C - float** function parameter not passing values

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, parameter-passing

I pass a matrix as a float** pointer to a function, and the only thing this function does is print the elements that are in the matrix the pointer points to. However, the elements are all 0 in the print statement. I am suspicious that I have initialized the pointer xadjm correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void which(float **adj_mat, int n) {
  for (int tt=0; tt<n; tt++) {
    for (int cc=0; cc<n; cc++) {
      if (cc==(n-1)) {
        printf("%f-\n", *(adj_mat+tt*n+cc));
      } else {
        printf("%f-", *(adj_mat+tt*n+cc));
      }
    }
  }
}


int main() {
  int n=5;
  float adjm[5][5] = {{0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}};
  float **xadjm = (float**) adjm;
  which(xadjm, n);

  return(0);
}
```

Output of executed code:

```
0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-
0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-
0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-
0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-
0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-0.000000-
```

Comment: [C pointer to two dimensional array](//stackoverflow.com/q/14808908)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing an invalid cast.

You're attempting to convert a `float[5][5]` to a `float **`.  While arrays do decay to a pointer to its first element, that **only** applies to the outermost array dimension.  It does **not** apply to inner dimensions.

What you can do however is specify the dimensions of the array in the parameter list to `which`:

```
void which(int n, float adj_mat[n][n]) {
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
which(n, adjm);
```

You're also printing incorrectly:

```
  if (cc==(n-1)) {
    printf("%f-\n", *(adj_mat+tt*n+cc));
  } else {
    printf("%f-", *(adj_mat+tt*n+cc));
  }
```

The expression `*(adj_mat+tt*n+cc)` gives you a `float *`, not a `float`.  Instead do the following:

```
  if (cc==(n-1)) {
    printf("%f-\n", adj_mat[tt][cc]);
  } else {
    printf("%f-", adj_mat[tt][cc]);
  }
```

Comment: I would say that your approach isn't ideal because I do not want to pass a matrix as paramters to functions. Imagine if the matrix was a LOT larger. I'm using pet example sizes for this post, but in reality, my matrices will be a lot larger. I want to use pointers instead when communicating between functions where the memory blocks of info are.

Comment: You're not actually passing a full matrix as a parameter.  Anytime you pass an array (regardless of how many dimensions) to a function, you're passing a pointer to the first member.  So `int *` and `int []` as parameters are identical.  In your case, `float[n][n]` is the same as `float (*)[n]`.  So in reality you're only passing a pointer.

Comment: Is that for real? It seems deceptive because it looks like if you pass an arg that is declared like float arg[n][n], that you are sending that block of memory? Can you point me to a reference so I can verify. Your code does work, so I'll def give you the vote. Just want to make sure what I ultimately decide to do is the smartest overall.

Comment: @areyoujokingme [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.7.6.3p7: *A declaration of a parameter as "array of
type" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type",  where  the  type  qualifiers  (if  any)  are  those  specified  within  the [ and ] of  the array  type  derivation.*